# Array of arrays of objects - find object value occurance and return true/false (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of array of object as follows:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'xxx',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      itemName: 'yyy',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'aaa',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      itemName: 'kkk',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'kkk',
      ...
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      itemName: 'yyy',
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
]
```

I am trying to check if any itemName from objects inside arrays equals given string, but I stuck at the solution that keeps these arrays with such object in one array. Here is my solution:

```
  function isNameAcrossData(givenString){
    return arr.map(arrItem =>
      arrItem.find(item => item.itemId === givenString)
    );
  }
```

My solution doesn't return boolean but just one array with objects, that contain givenString and undefined as last array element. How to modify it to return just true/false value?

Comment: btw, what do you want to check? name or id? please add the wanted result with an example.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `.some` inside a `.some`, to see if some of the arrays have at least one element inside matching the condition:

```js
const isNameAcrossData = givenString => arr.some(
  subarr => subarr.some(
    ({ itemName }) => itemName === givenString
  )
);

const arr=[[{id:1,itemName:"xxx"},{id:1,itemName:"yyy"}],[{id:2,itemName:"aaa"},{id:2,itemName:"kkk"}],[{id:3,itemName:"kkk"},{id:3,itemName:"yyy"}]];

console.log(isNameAcrossData('xxx'));
console.log(isNameAcrossData('doesntexist'));
```

You could also flatten the outer array first:

```js
const isNameAcrossData = givenString => arr.flat().some(
  ({ itemName }) => itemName === givenString
);

const arr=[[{id:1,itemName:"xxx"},{id:1,itemName:"yyy"}],[{id:2,itemName:"aaa"},{id:2,itemName:"kkk"}],[{id:3,itemName:"kkk"},{id:3,itemName:"yyy"}]];

console.log(isNameAcrossData('xxx'));
console.log(isNameAcrossData('doesntexist'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with `some` and return an array of boolean with using the wanted property.

```js
function mapHasValue(key, value) {
    return data.map(array => array.some(item => item[key] === value));
}

var data = [[{ id: 1, itemName: 'xxx' }, { id: 1, itemName: 'yyy' }], [{ id: 2, itemName: 'aaa' }, { id: 2, itemName: 'kkk' }], [{ id: 3, itemName: 'kkk' }, { id: 3, itemName: 'yyy' }]];

console.log(mapHasValue('id', 3));
```

Comment: `some`, not `every`.

Comment: It's details like that that make an answer "wrong" or "correct", though. If the question is unclear, you should close-vote it. But it appears 2 other users managed to understand the question, any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns

```js
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

because map returns an array so this approach won't work

You have first to loop through all the data and check inside then outside the loop assign to some variable true if there is a match.

Basically you have to return after you loop the data. 
Working example for both cases:

```js
const arr=[[{id:1,itemName:"xxx"},{id:1,itemName:"yyy"}],[{id:2,itemName:"aaa"},{id:2,itemName:"kkk"}],[{id:3,itemName:"kkk"},{id:3,itemName:"yyy"}]];

function isNameAcrossData(givenString){
    let isMatch = false; 
    arr.map(childArr => {
        childArr.map(obj => obj.itemName === givenString ? isMatch = true : null);
    });
    return isMatch;
}
console.log(isNameAcrossData('kkk'));
console.log(isNameAcrossData('bbb'));
```